# Textbox with jQuery datepicker OnTextChanged not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a asp:textbox with a OnTextChanged event that I want to fire when ever a new date is selected from the jQuery datepicker that is bound to it but when selecting a date, the OnTextChanged never fires. It fires if I change the text 'by hand' but I want to force the user to select the date from the datepicker. I need to run server side code each time the date is changed. I have tried using the onSelect method on the datepicker but was unable to get it to call the method.

Here is my client side code:

```
 function pageLoad() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        constrainInput: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd D M yy'
    });
}

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPickupDate" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtPickupDate_TextChanged" CssClass="datepicker"
       AutoPostBack="true" >
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPickupTime" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
```

Greatly appreciate any help

Update: Was asked to include the TextChanged function. Didn't post it initially as it isn't firing the method and figured it didn't affect the solution but regardless, here it is:

```
protected void txtPickupDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime pickupDate = DateTime.Parse(txtPickupDate.Text);
        //do things with the date
    }
```

Comment: where is this txtPickupDate_TextChanged function..?

Comment: Just realised you asked where it is not what it is.. sorry Sudhir. It is in the .cs file for the aspx page that the datepicker is on

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested your code and the TextChanged server side method is being fired when the date is being selected on the datepicker.

One slight change I made was refactoring the jquery to reside within $(document).ready() function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        constrainInput: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd D M yy'
    });
});
</script>
```

See the entire code below.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DatePickerTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApp.DatePickerTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPickupDate" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtPickupDate_TextChanged" CssClass="datepicker" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        constrainInput: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd D M yy'
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And server side

```
protected void txtPickupDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DateTime pickupDate = DateTime.Parse(txtPickupDate.Text); 
}
```

EDIT as per comment below:

To allow the TextChanged event to continue to fire after post back you can use

.live() if not using the latest version of jquery as it is now [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').live('click', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({
            constrainInput: true, dateFormat: 'dd D M yy'
        }).focus();
    });
});
```

or .[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with the latest version of JQuery 1.7 and upwards

```
$('body').on('click', '.datepicker', function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        constrainInput: true, dateFormat: 'dd D M yy'
    }).focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas! I ended up performing the jquery bind to the datepicker as you suggested and also on pageload (otherwise the datepicker doesn't work after the post back) and it is all working as it should :)

Comment: @Washburn - see above for how to bind to the datepicker after post back

Comment: Could you please explain why attaching the event with `on` function works on postback while `document.ready` does not?

Comment: Hi @BornToCode the on() function can bind events to elements dynamically added to the dom whereas document.ready binds events to the elements available when the document fully reloads. So the postback is only a partial postback dynamically adding and removing elements.