# Postback on Textbox embeded with JQuery Datetimepicker not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page with a textbox embedded with a jquery datetimepicker. I want my user to be able to manually type in the date or select it from the datetimepicker. When they've typed or selected a date, a gridview on the same page is refreshed based on the date.

When the user TYPES in a date the postback is triggered which then refreshes the gridview, however, when the date is selected, postback is not triggered and the gridview is not refreshed.

My question is why would the textbox not recognize that it's value has changed when the date is selected and how do I force postback when the date is selected?

Below is my current code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/jquery.datepick.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= txtTransDate.ClientID %>").datepick({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' })
    });

</script>
....  
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTransDate" class="field" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
```

I tried re-binding the gridview on txtTransDate_TextChanged, but it was only called when the user manually typed in the date. I also tried using the CalendarExtender as per solutions found online, but couldn't seem to get it working.

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtTransDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server"        
 TargetControlID="txtTransDate"> </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried manually causing a postback upon selecting a date with the datepicker's callback? My idea is that when they select a date the TextBox doesn't lose focus so the change event doesn't happen.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075043/textbox-with-jquery-datepicker-ontextchanged-not-firing

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. Zeeshanef, I did try that method during my research, but couldn't get it to work cause I found that when ever the user selects a date, the textbox value was not cleared, so the selected date was added which causes the OnTextChanged event to pick up an invalid date.